# Customize input checkbox indeterminate

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I want input checkbox indeterminate to look like this [indeterminate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5KVj.png)

i mean not the color, but that half filled type of appearance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add a code example?

Comment: Just use a CSS gradient that runs diagonally from the top left to bottom right corner, with a color stop at 50%.

Comment: myCheckbox[type="checkbox"]:indeterminate {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black 50%, grey 50%);} I tried like this. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a `label` to style the checkbox, and `js` to trigger the indeterminate state of the checkbox. Here's an example:

```js
function toggle(demo) {
   if (demo.readOnly) demo.checked=demo.readOnly=false;
   else if (!demo.checked) demo.readOnly=demo.indeterminate=true;
}
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label
{
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  border: 2px solid #212121;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
{
  background: aqua;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:indeterminate + label
{
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, aqua 50%, lightgrey 50%);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='valuable' id="test" onclick="toggle(this)"/><label for="test"></label>
</div>
```